# Problen with jquery and ajax parsing JSON. Only working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this jquery code:

```
var baseURl = 'http://www.testdomain.com';
bindItemImage("230015");

function bindItemImage(_itemCode) {
  $.ajax({
    url: baseURl + 'v3/api/itemimage/' + _itemCode,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        var item = $.parseJSON(data);
       var file = baseURl + item.File;
       $('.itemPhoto').attr('src', file);
    }
   });
```

}

it displays the image just fine in firefox but not in IE or chrome.
Chrome and IE return the right data but I get a JS error message "Cannot read property 'File' of null"

here is the JS fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/C8Xjy/3/

Thank you

Comment: `item` is coming up as undefined in the other browsers. Try removing `baseURl` from the `url: ` first, then add `dataType: "json"` and remove `$.parseJSON`

Comment: Are you attempting to do this call cross-domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're expecting a json response you set `dataType` to `"json"`, using `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` is for when you're sending json in your request. Also when you specify json as the data type it will already be parsed when passed to the success handler.

```
$.ajax({
  url: baseURl + 'v3/api/itemimage/' + _itemCode,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    var file = baseURl + data.File;
    $('.itemPhoto').attr('src', file);
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/C8Xjy/7/)

Comment: @vts if this is a cross domain request then `$.ajax` doesn't support cross domain requests in Internet Explorer you'll have to use [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060(v=vs.85).aspx)